# Prepend a value to all the cells of a column in Excel

Tags: excel

I currently have a excel spreadsheet like this:

```
Product ID  |   Thumb Image   |   HR Image 
001            my_image_1.jpg    my_image_HR_1.jpg
002            my_image_2.jpg    my_image_HR_2.jpg
003            my_image_3.jpg    my_image_HR_3.jpg 
...
...and so on (10,000 rows)
```

I need to prepend a url to the images, so it would look like this:

```
Product ID  |              Thumb Image              |          HR Image 
001           http://www.website.com/my_image_1.jpg   http://www.website.com/my_image_HR_1.jpg
002           http://www.website.com/my_image_2.jpg   http://www.website.com/my_image_HR_3.jpg
003           http://www.website.com/my_image_3.jpg   http://www.website.com/my_image_HR_3.jpg
...
...and so on (10,000 rows)
```

Is there a formula for that? How can I accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the formula '=$C$1&B3' like in the following image, and fill down. Similar formula for the HR Image column.

[image]

After the values are what you want, you can copy them and paste over the thumb image by right clicking, after selecting the cells and selecting "Paste Special Values".  After that you can delete the added C column (and header row).